# Is it illegal to refrain from selling stock based on insider information?

Tags: united-states, stocks, law, legal, insider-trading

If I were planning to sell my stock of the company I work for, then see a non-public draft of the next quarterly report that will make the stock go way up, and cancel my plan to sell based on that information, would this be illegal insider trading?

Comment: what company?! (sorry, couldn't help it)

Comment: @Rocky - haha, now THAT would definitely be illegal, but again, hypothetical.

Comment: @hamboy legal for us, NDA problem for you:)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a hypothetical scenario.

Comment: Nobody will stop you from doing so, but the moment any law agency got wind of it you are in big trouble.

Comment: As long as the plan is only in your head there is no issue. If you have placed an order in the market or with a broker and subsequently cancel it that would be insider trading. Also note that some companies have periods within which employees are not allowed to trade in the company's stock. If in doubt it is best to ask to the relevant people in your company before acting.

Comment: @littleadv I think there are plenty of questions about hypothetical scenarios that are on topic. This question might be off-topic because it is a legal question rather than an actual question about finance.

Comment: @assylias *not* placing a trade based on insider information is also illegal. Making *any* decision is. Provable? As I said - a totally different question.

Comment: @littleadv I know the European framework better, but I doubt that one would qualify an action as insider trading if it doesn't involve some form of interaction with the market... Cancelling an order is an interaction - never placing it is not. But as always in those matters, the devil is in the details and if in doubt the op should seek professional advice.

Comment: Another twist would be if you were about to sell, and right before you did someone revealed insider information telling you that you should indeed sell. Would your sale suddenly become illegal?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I will restrict my answer to Canada and the US, the only jurisdictions with which I am familiar.

Contrary to the other answer, the statutory and regulatory insider trading regimes in both the US and Canada require an actual transaction ("purchase or sale of securities") to occur. If no transaction occurs, there is no insider trading.

There is a possible exception: I would be interested to see case law test the question of whether engaging in non-transacted interactions with the market (i.e. adding passive liquidity to the order book) on the basis of inside information might qualify as insider trading in the US under the vaguer 10b statutory text. I suspect not, but I can't state that with any certainty.

Comment: This may be a good answer, but you could greatly improve it by providing references for your assertion.

Answer (score 7):

Making any decision based on insider information is illegal. Whether the US Government will be able to prove these facts in court is a different question. That said, your post here may be brought in as the proof (and if you think you're anonymous here - think again).

Comment: Fortunately, this is hypothetical

Comment: Trading based on inside information is illegal, we know of no precedent for "not trading" based on inside information, so we can only offer conjecture on whether that will be ruled illegal. Your example with Martha Stewart below is of a stop-loss trade order. Do you have an example of a non-trade that was prosecuted?

Comment: Note that there is no actual legal statute that prohibits anything called insider trading.  The legal statute that has been used as the basis for insider trading cases is the one from the Securities Exchange Act of 1934 that prohibits unfair market manipulation.  What "unfair market manipulation" actually means has only been established over the decades by the judges' written decisions in the various trials that have occurred -- not by any codified statute.  See [these](http://tinyurl.com/lx34jnw) [two](http://tinyurl.com/mu92dl5) super informative recent Bloomberg articles.

Comment: @dg99 so.... the judges agreed that it is illegal then, right?

Comment: Not quite. The body of decisions now says that for insider trading to have occurred, 5 criteria (see links above) must have been met. And since those criteria involve 2 people, it's essentially impossible for a single person to "insider trade" by himself. Now appeals courts have begun striking down verdicts where any of the 5 criteria was not met, and the language in their decisions has begun to question whether these criteria even imply the "market manipulation" that the 1934 Act intended. Of course, the SEC will continue to pressure people into settling rather than take their chances ...

Comment: @dg99 you're talking about "outsiders" doing insider trading. For example, Martha Stewart fits this bill. The OP however discusses a case where *insider* does insider trading. There's no 2 persons, where one is tipping the other - the OP is tipping himself here.

Comment: Looking for an answer that cites the law or court precedent. This answer is not helpful.

Comment: @hamboy Then you might re-post on https://law.stackexchange.com as most here are not lawyers (granted there is a large overlap)

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer becomes super clear when you consider a textbook variation of the same situation.

If you were to *buy* the stock based on insider information (seeing a nonpublic quarterly report), it is clearly insider trading.

In both cases, **nonpublic information** leads to an **action** that results in **higher profits**.

It's also important to define what "planning to sell" means. If you just thought about it, this is an ethical dilemma. If you had an open sell order, there was a record of your intent to sell.

Comment: Not selling is not an action, it is a lack of action.

Comment: @NathanL Cancelling a sell order is an action.

Comment: Not if you never place one. A sell order isn’t a “plan” per the OP. Once you’ve opened an order, you’ve gone from plan to execution.

Answer (score 0):

Not trading on insider information is not insider trading. Generally there must be a trade transacted. There could be an exception if you have an un-transacted order that you cancel, such as a limit order, but I don't know if that has ever been court tested.

One problem with this scenario is if you possess insider information and you proceed with a planned transaction even though it does not meet your best interests. Technically insider trading doesn't require you to benefit. The best advice is to not conduct any trades that involve insider trading, whether they would benefit you or not.

To be extra careful don't publicize your trading plans. If you tell the world you want to make a trade then cancel because of insider information you might be at risk. I'm not saying you committed a crime but there's no reason to test the waters.

Think about this scenario: conspiracy to commit murder is a crime. However to be charged with the crime one must have communicated the plans or have evidence of planning. If you plan to murder someone completely in your head but never tell anyone, write anything down, or possess a murder weapon, no crime has occurred. People think evil things without acting on them constantly. Thought crime is not crime.

Comment: *Conspiracy* to commit murder is a crime, but *planning* a murder is not.  If you write your plan down and purchase a (legal) weapon, then you still have not committed a crime.